# How to zip a file Upload

Tags: java, javascript, web, primefaces

Use the component p: upload the primefaces, and had the need to zip / compress files that are sent by this component.
The idea is to reduce the data traffic, improving the usability of the connection.

Does anyone have any idea how I can do this, or something for me to start researching, or have seen something?

Comment: Unless you run a plugin in the browser with file system access, you probably will not be able to zip the file before sending it.  There are lots of ways to zip a file once received by the server.  Alternately, what about suggesting to the user to zip files for better upload performance?

Answer (score 0):

wysiwyg editers....

fkedit
htmleditor

the box i am replying in right now with the B/I/link/quotes/braces... etc.... buttons at the top.  most of these type of editors out there, normally have some sort of file manager with built in zip functionality. normally as an additional plugin to the textarea editor though.

www.moodle.org  file manager i don't remmeber if it was in 1.8 or 1.9 or 2.0 or 2.1 that had some different zip manager built directly into javascript (client side) along with everything built for php server side zip handling.

www.joomola.org  you might look at some of there extensions for file management.